# Function within a function in php

Tags: php, function

I made a form for a website where user posts data. For filtering and validation the string I wrote 3 functions for that but now its seems ugly when i call 3 functions in different lines. The data coming through the post method. I am not talking about nested functions here.

Can I call A function within another function like this?

php:

```
function apple($dates) {
    return $dates;
}

function mango($sause) {
    $mango = apple($sause);
    return $mango;
}
```

Comment: You could have just run the code you wrote in your question and answered the question yourself. `:/`

Comment: That's like eating without taking a picture of it

Comment: haha xD and @Sammitch yes i should have done that but i didn't know this is the right way for using multiple functions or not anyway i need some advise on this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word - yes. A function's code can definitely call another function.

Comment: Or even itself.

Comment: @Andreas True 'dat

Comment: @bessy yup. Although it's probably a good idea to give your functions more descriptive names than `apple` and `mango`.

Comment: haha lol. First i wrote apple sause then i delete it lol any way Thanks for the
 quick response.